# DevOps build-pipeline overview & sound trigger on fail

Tags: audio, triggers, azure-devops, build-pipeline

I want to setup a monitor were my development team can see the current status of our build-pipelines. When a build-pipeline fails, I want to trigger a sound. I don’t know if it is even possible in Azure DevOps but that’s why I’m asking it here.
Also, if somebody has some good advice for configuring this monitoring ‘dashboard’, please let me know!

Kind regards,

Wouter

Answer (score 1):

You can create your on own dashboard ([Add, rename, and delete dashboards in Azure DevOps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/dashboards?view=azure-devops)) with build-in pipeline widgets ([Azure Pipelines widgets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/widget-catalog?view=azure-devops#azure-pipelines-widgets)). Additionally, you can use extensions from the marketplace:

- [Team Project Health](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.TeamProjectHealth)
- [Project Tile](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=heymrcarter.ProjectTile)
- [CI/CD Dashboard](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=experta.cicd-dashboard)

You can try [CatLight](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=catlight.catlight) for notifications on a local workplace.